# autowire="autodetect" its property is possible in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Please Help me for this problem. I have configuration in spring for autowire="autodetect". I want to use it but Appear this error
"cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'autodetect' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[default, no, byName, byType, constructor]'. It must be a value from the enumeration."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

<bean  id="circle" class="com.Circle_Constructor" autowire="autodetect" ></bean>    
<bean class="com.Point" id="point">
    <property name="x" value="0"></property>
    <property name="y" value="0"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: I want to use autowire="autodetect" property, but i got error like this

Comment: *Like what?* Please add a stacktrace to the question.

Comment: I got this error in Console "cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'autodetect' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[default, no, byName, byType, constructor]'. It must be a value from the enumeration."

Comment: No, as the error tells you, there is no such available `autodect` property. What made you think there is? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I am student and I am learning about it so i use this little configuration, can  you suggest me what can i do? autowire="autodetect" property is not allow in spring? Thanks You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is:

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd"

Autodetect functionality is applied when used with the 2.5 and 2.0 schemas. It has been deprecate from 3.0+

try:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

 <bean  id="circle" class="com.Circle_Constructor" autowire="autodetect" >    </bean>    
 <bean class="com.Point" id="point">
    <property name="x" value="0"></property>
    <property name="y" value="0"></property>
 </bean>

 </beans>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You for reply me and hlep me, I am little confuse that now in spring 4.2 so we cant use autowire="autodetect" so what we use for this?

Comment: One way would be to use @Autowired.
Though I generally don't specify schema in my xmls and always tend to use the version default. I think there should be no problem in using a 2.5 schema in 4.2 atleast in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much for give me time and suggest me hope i will get soon